# Fullcalendar month view how to add a custom column

Tags: fullcalendar

There are way to add a custom/total column in a month view?

[image]

Comment: You'd have to fork the code for the "month" view and write your own custom code for it (see [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js) for more info. It may not be simple). After all "total" is not a day of the week, it's not something the maintainers of the calendar anticipated at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
eventAfterAllRender: function (view) {
    $(view.headRowEl).find('tr > .cc-total').remove();
    $(view.el).find('td.fc-day-number').closest('tr').find('.cc-total').remove();

    $(view.headRowEl).find('tr').append('<th class="fc-day-header fc-widget-header fc-sun cc-total">Total</th>');
    $(view.el).find('td.fc-day-number').closest('tr').append('<td class="cc-total"></td>');

    var rows = $(view.el).find('.fc-row.fc-week');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        $(rows[i]).find('td.fc-day').closest('tr').find('.cc-total').remove();
        $(rows[i]).find('td.fc-day').closest('tr').append('<td class="cc-total" style="vertical-align: middle;" align="center"><b>' + total + '</b></td>');
    }
}
```